# Pause command is run out of order when running "start cmd /c" multiple times

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a script like this:

```
@start /b cmd /c net stop "Service"
@start /b cmd /c net stop "Service"
@start /b cmd /c net stop "Service"
@start /b cmd /c net stop "Service"
@start /b cmd /c net stop "Service"
pause
```

However, the `pause` command gets executed before all of the lines above it in the script have been executed. I need to use `@start /b cmd /c` so that it doesn't have to wait for the "Stopping Service..." after each service (about 100) of time. Is there any way to tell cmd to wait until all of the `@start /b cmd /c net stop "Service"` commands have completed then run the pause?

To see what I'm talking about run this batch file:

```
@start /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /b cmd /c echo Hello
pause
```

Instead of the `Pause` occurring after all of the `Hello` have been printed, it happens in the middle:

[image]

Comment: Can't answer at the moment since this is on hold - I ran the batch and the pause does get thrown in there before the last echo. My workaround is to just add a `timeout 1 /nobreak >nul` before your pause. This may need tuning depending on what services your stopping or if they can cause issues, but at least for your example the invisible one second delay seemed to do the trick.

Comment: It still doesnt work the timeout still goes in between the @start /b cmd /c echo Hello

I dont want to add a timeout because sometimes it takes long to end the services and sometimes it ends them quick.

Comment: is it pausing between each line for you? when I did the echo test you suggested it only paused once right before the final hello.

Comment: for me the pause was at the end but when Im running time consuming tasks such as the net stop, the pause command goes in between the net stops, for example     


The service has stopped successfully     

Press any key to continue     

The service has stopped successfully     

The service has stopped successfully     

The service has stopped successfully     

Like that even though the pause is at the end. Sorry it looks unclear i couldnt press enter like i could in the main question.

Comment: Welcome. I took considerable liberty in an attempt to consolidate your question in order to make the problem you're facing more clear. Please review it and make any adjustments as needed. In particular I couldn't tell how to handle the sentence that says, "I need to use @start /b cmd /c for sake of time." This is a very interesting question and I look forward to you're getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks, greatly appreciated, how did you put the commands in boxes I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: @PolisP2 Click [edit] and see what the source looks like. Any question or answer has its own `edit` button, so if you see some nice formatting you can peek and learn how it's done; and experiment (without saving, unless you do want to save). There's also [this help page](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: “I need to use ``@start /b cmd /c`` for sake of time” — because I don’t want to wait for the “time consuming tasks such as the `net stop`” — but I want “to wait until all of the ``@start /b cmd /c net stop "Service"`` commands have completed”. No, this is still unclear.

Comment: Is there some reason why you choose not to use the "wait" switch? for example "@start /b /wait cmd /c echo hello" works if you write that 10 time and then pause... why do you choose not to "wait"?

Comment: ```@Larryc``` Ill give that try. I tried it, and if I ***do*** use ```/wait``` theres no point in using ```@start /b cmd /c``` since when I tried ```@start /b /wait cmd /c```, the Service is Stopping... forced all the rest of the ~100 services to wait, and then next one forced the rest to wait and the next and so on, so that doesnt work. The benefit of using ```@start /b cmd /c``` is so that all the services end simultaneously, but it even skips through things that dont have the ```@start /b cmd /c``` in front of them such as the pause command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `start` starts an aplication in it's own context, appart from what you current console is doing, that's why when it's done it will return the output, once your current terminal is done with whatever is doing. That's why even though you send all this start command, your pause is not waiting for all of them to finish It's just waiting long enough to start the processes, That's why your `pause` appears in the midle of them it's just a thing of timing.

So to solve you problem you can wait for them to finish with `/wait` or making a call to a second batch script, this way you can wait for some commands and not others, if you preffer:

Wait technique for your script

```
@start /wait /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /wait /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /wait /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /wait /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /wait /b cmd /c echo Hello
@start /wait /b cmd /c echo Hello
pause
```

Technique with laucher script

```
@echo off
title Laucher

:: This scripts don't need to be waited
start /b cmd /c 'script1.bat'
:: This script needs to be waited
start /wait /b cmd /c 'script2.bat'
```

Script1

```
@echo off
title Script to run without waiting

SomeProcessThatDoesn'tNeedsToBeWaited
```

Script2

```
@echo off
title Script to run to be waited

SomeProcessThatNeedsToBeWaited
```

cheers